# SwiftUI: Form pushes all navigation links on navigation stack

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-form, swiftui-navigationstack

The idea is to use a Settings View in my App using a Form. However, it seems the Form itself pushes all NavigationLinks from the List view onto the navigation stack (at once). The typical (correct?) expected behaviour when not wrapped in a Form, is that the id of the NavigationLink is only pushed onto the stack when used. See also code.

Code where the behaviour is as expected - only values for NavigationLinks that are used are pushed onto the stack :

```
struct NumberView: View {

    @Binding var navigationPath: [Int]
    var number: Int
    var max: Int

    var body: some View {
        let next: Int = number < max ? number + 1 : 1
        return Form {
            Section {
                Text("This is sheet with number: \(number)")

                NavigationLink("Progress to number: \(next)", value: next)

                Button("Go back") {
                    print("navigationPath: \(navigationPath)")
                    navigationPath.removeLast()
                }

                Button("Go back to root") { // unwind to root
                    print("navigationPath: \(navigationPath)")
                    navigationPath.removeAll()
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Pick")
        }

    }
}

struct SettingsView: View {
    
    @State var navigationPath: [Int] = []
    private let numberArray: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack (path: $navigationPath) {
            List(numberArray, id: \.self) { number in
                NavigationLink("Pick a number: \(number)", value: number)
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { number in
                NumberView(navigationPath: $navigationPath, number: number, max: numberArray.max()!)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Pick your number")
        }
    }
}
```

Now the same code, however, with the List in Settings View wrapped into a Form. In this scenario all NavigationLinks are pushed onto the stack regardless of the actual navigation itself.

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    
    @State var navigationPath: [Int] = []
    private let numberArray: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack (path: $navigationPath) {
            Form {
                List(numberArray, id: \.self) { number in
                    NavigationLink("Pick a number: \(number)", value: number)
                }
                .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { number in
                    NumberView(navigationPath: $navigationPath, number: number, max: numberArray.max()!)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Pick your number")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution? Struggling on this now

Answer (score 0):

Simply move the `navigationDestination()` modifier from the `List` view to the `Form` view.

```
struct SettingsView: View {

    @State var navigationPath: [Int] = []
    private let numberArray: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack (path: $navigationPath) {
            Form {
                List(numberArray, id: \.self) { number in
                    NavigationLink("Pick a number: \(number)", value: number)
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { number in
                NumberView(navigationPath: $navigationPath, number: number, max: numberArray.max()!)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Pick your number")
        }
    }
}
```